# Registry class in netstandard1.6;net46 projects

Tags: c#, registry, .net-standard

I'm porting an application from .NET 4.0 to support both .NET 4.6 and .NET Standard 1.6 to be used as a cross-platform MSBuild task.

This application makes use of all kinds of stuff that we took for granted as Windows developers. One of them is the `Registry` and `RegistryKey` classes. That is no longer available in .NET Standard 1.6.

What can I do to make use of it on any Windows platform (.NET Framework and .NET Core) and ignore it on other platforms (.NET Core only)? I have compiler symbols defined for each target framework, so I can `#if` out the specific code. But currently the two classes are unknown for the .NET Standard target, with red underlining.

Comment: Are you targeting both `net46` and `netstandard1.6`? If so, just use `#if NET46` and you should be fine...

Comment: I could do that, but `dotnet msbuild` running on Windows needs the registry lookups. That's a CLR or OS selection, not a build target selection.

Comment: Well if you want it at compile-time, it *is* a build target selection matter. You can't expect to use classes that aren't available in .NET Core when targeting netstandard. You could load the relevant assembly via reflection if you detect at execution time that you're on Windows and running in the full framework...

Comment: So I guess .NET Standard 1.6 doesn't contain registry access? That would make it pretty useless for my case. I'd need to retarget to .NET Std 2.0 then, I believe that covers it. Everything else would work by now.

Comment: I would be surprised if netstandard2.0 included registry access, given that it's meant to be portable. If it *does* include it, I'd expect it to throw exceptions when running on non-Windows.

Comment: Bear in mind that registry access isn't even under `System.*` - it's in the `Microsoft.Win32` namespace.

Comment: Looking at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey?view=netframework-4.7 it may be in .NET Core, but not netstandard.

Comment: Oh great. Good bye Registry. Good bye all that information. Welcome stupid software. Need to find a solution. Maybe I'll write my own P/Invoke wrapper.

Comment: It's not clear what you'd *expect* it to do when running on a platform other than Windows. You need to accept that portability comes with some limitations. I've already suggested that you could invoke it with reflection, potentially.

Answer (score 0):

.NET Standard 1.6 (and apparently also 2.0) have no support for accessing the Windows registry. So there are only two options:

1. Call `reg query` with appropriate arguments and parse its output. This seems like a complicated task so I didn't investigate that.
2. P/Invoke the Windows API functions `RegOpenKeyEx`, `RegCloseKey` and `RegQueryValueEx`. Here's the code file I use for that: https://gist.github.com/ygoe/bb776fac530176b08519a5314d53fcb6